# undefined parameters in /etc/postfix/master.cf

Tags: 18.04, postfix

The [default master.cf file](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postfix/postfix_3.3.0.orig.tar.gz) in a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18 seems to contain some undefined parameters:

Under both the `submission` block and the `smtps` block:

```
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
```

What's going on here?  Is this a bug?  Or is the package maintainer expecting us to define these ourselves?

This came up for me yesterday when I got these warnings while installing a new package:

```
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
```

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @xurshid29 - I think it's just slop left over from some earlier package.  Those variables aren't defined anywhere and no one bothered to take them out.  Since they come commented by default, they won't cause issues out of the box if you leave them alone.

Comment: This seems not come from the Ubuntu package, but the original postfix default config. It was introduced with this commit https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/commit/99ff75430d5c908879caffc1125680ed68019021#diff-6f25157451e1bcb001a0a6926795486bR23

Answer (score 7):

You can get rid of the error messages by adding the following in the main.cf file for postfix:

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = mua_sender_restrictions, mua_client_restrictions, mua_helo_restrictions

mua_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject

mua_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject

mua_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
```

Save main.cf and the postfix reload, then postfix check.  You should see nothing being printed.  That's what I did to remove the errors from my build.  It seems to be a defaults left over from the build.  I believe that you can comment those 3 lines out in the master.cf and then you can use `smtpd_client_restrictions, smtpd_sender_restrictions`, `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, and `smtpd_helo_restrictions` in the main.cf for postfix.